# Rebol to-string strange behavior: how can I correct?

Tags: rebol

```
>> to-string pick [abc/def] 1
== "abcdef"
>>
```

How can I get "abc/def" instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mold pick [abc/def] 1
 == "abc/def"
```

Or:

```
form pick [abc/def] 1
=="abc/def"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using string, which is delimited by {}, you can then use the ^(xx) format to insert an ASCII character by hex code.

Example:

> `>> to-string pick [{abc^(2F)def}] 1`
>   `== "abc/def""`
>   `>>`

Use the ASCII table [here](http://www.asciitable.com) if you need more codes.
For more information on REBOL strings see [this link](http://www.rebol.org/art-display-article.r?article=m298xx).

Comment: That works, thanks for the link, never thought about reading it before, now I will.

Answer (score 1):

The `to-` family of functions were changed in Rebol 3, and your code now provides the string you want.  OTOH, `form` works in 2 and 3.

Are you using `pick [abc/def] 1` because you wanted the literal path abc/def (and not have the interpreter try to pick def out of abc)?  You can use quote to get that effect more simply:

```
>> form quote abc/def
== "abc/def"
```

And then there's the shorthand:

```
>> form 'abc/def
== "abc/def"
```